How to Install rgdal in R version 4.4.1?
I would like to install rgdal but my numerous attempts have failed so far.
I was trying to download the package using the archive https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/ . I have tried the download for the most recent version and an older version.
I will provide my code and look forward to any response on potential reasons for the error or an example of a code for rgdal installation which works.
Thank you!
Here is the code (from the console) with checks for GDAL, GEOS, PROJ and Rtools installation.
> # List of required packages for rgdal
> required_packages <- c("sp", "raster", "sf", "terra", "pkgbuild", "devtools")
> # Check for and install any missing packages
> for (package in required_packages) {
+   if (!require(package, character.only = TRUE)) {
+     install.packages(package)
+   }
+ }
Loading required package: sp
Loading required package: raster
Loading required package: sf
Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
Loading required package: terra
terra 1.7.78
Loading required package: pkgbuild
Loading required package: devtools
Loading required package: usethis

Attaching package: ‘devtools’

The following object is masked from ‘package:pkgbuild’:

    build

> # Load the packages
> lapply(required_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE

[[5]]
[1] TRUE

[[6]]
[1] TRUE

> sf::sf_extSoftVersion() #it seems that GDAL GEOS and PROJ are installed
          GEOS           GDAL         proj.4 GDAL_with_GEOS     USE_PROJ_H 
      "3.12.1"        "3.8.4"        "9.3.1"         "true"         "true" 
          PROJ 
       "9.3.1" 
> #check Rtools
> system("gcc --version")
gcc.exe (GCC) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[1] 0
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> source_directory <- "F:/rgdal_1.2-20/rgdal"
> devtools::load_all(source_directory)
ℹ Loading rgdal
ℹ Re-compiling rgdal (debug build)
── R CMD INSTALL ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  installing *source* package 'rgdal' ...
   ** package 'rgdal' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   ** using staged installation
   
      **********************************************
      WARNING: this package has a configure script
            It probably needs manual configuration
      **********************************************
   
   
   ** libs
   using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 13.2.0'
   using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 13.2.0'
   using C++11
   rm -f rgdal.dll OGR_write.o gdal-bindings.o init.o inverser.o local_stubs.o ogr_geom.o ogr_polygons.o ogr_proj.o ogrdrivers.o ogrsource.o projectit.o
   mkdir -p ../inst
   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" --vanilla "../tools/winlibs.R" 2.2.3
   cp -r ../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/share/gdal ../inst/
   cp -r ../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/share/proj ../inst/
   g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/include/gdal -I../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/include/geos -I../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/include/proj -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall -gdwarf-2 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c OGR_write.cpp -o OGR_write.o
   In file included from C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/13.2.0/include/c++/stdlib.h:36
                    from ../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/include/gdal/cpl_port.h:138
                    from ../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/include/gdal/cpl_error.h:34
                    from ../windows/gdal2-2.2.3/include/gdal/cpl_string.h:35
                    from OGR_write.cpp:1
   C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/13.2.0/include/c++/cstdlib:141:11:error: at_quick_exithas not been declared in '::
     141 |   using ::at_quick_exit
         |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/13.2.0/include/c++/cstdlib:164:11:error: quick_exithas not been declared in '::
     164 |   using ::quick_exit
         |           ^~~~~~~~~~
   C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/13.2.0/include/c++/stdlib.h:43:14:error: at_quick_exithas not been declared in 'std
      43 |   using std::at_quick_exit
         |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/13.2.0/include/c++/stdlib.h:46:14:error: quick_exithas not been declared in 'std
      46 |   using std::quick_exit
         |              ^~~~~~~~~~
   make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:296: OGR_write.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgdal'
─  removing 'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgHCD5I/devtools_install_7adc49007db6/rgdal'
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Type .Last.error to see the more details.
> setwd('F:/')
> install.packages('rgdal_1.6-2.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rgdal' ...
** package 'rgdal' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 13.2.0'
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 13.2.0'
using C++11
rm -f rgdal.dll OGR_write.o gdal-bindings.o init.o inverser.o local_stubs.o ogr_geom.o ogr_polygons.o ogr_proj.o ogrdrivers.o ogrsource.o proj6.o proj_info6.o proj_network7.o projectit.o
cp -r "C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/share/gdal" ../inst/
cp -r "C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/share/proj" ../inst/
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c OGR_write.cpp -o OGR_write.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c gdal-bindings.cpp -o gdal-bindings.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c inverser.c -o inverser.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c local_stubs.c -o local_stubs.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ogr_geom.cpp -o ogr_geom.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ogr_polygons.c -o ogr_polygons.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ogr_proj.cpp -o ogr_proj.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ogrdrivers.cpp -o ogrdrivers.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ogrsource.cpp -o ogrsource.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c proj6.cpp -o proj6.o
proj6.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* transform_ng(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)':
proj6.cpp:696:54: warning: format '%n' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
  696 |             error("error in proj_transform_generic: %n of %n coordinates succeeded\n  %s", n1, n, errstr);
      |                                                     ~^                                     ~~
      |                                                      |                                     |
      |                                                      int*                                  size_t {aka long long unsigned int}
      |                                                     %lld
proj6.cpp:696:60: warning: format '%n' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
  696 |             error("error in proj_transform_generic: %n of %n coordinates succeeded\n  %s", n1, n, errstr);
      |                                                           ~^                                   ~
      |                                                            |                                   |
      |                                                            int*                                int
      |                                                           %d
proj6.cpp:710:52: warning: format '%n' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 2 has type 'size_t' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]
  710 |           error("error in proj_transform_generic: %n of %n coordinates succeeded\n  %s", n1, n, errstr);
      |                                                   ~^                                     ~~
      |                                                    |                                     |
      |                                                    int*                                  size_t {aka long long unsigned int}
      |                                                   %lld
proj6.cpp:710:58: warning: format '%n' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
  710 |           error("error in proj_transform_generic: %n of %n coordinates succeeded\n  %s", n1, n, errstr);
      |                                                         ~^                                   ~
      |                                                          |                                   |
      |                                                          int*                                int
      |                                                         %d
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c proj_info6.cpp -o proj_info6.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c proj_network7.cpp -o proj_network7.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -DPROJ_H_API -I'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/sp/include'   -I"C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c projectit.cpp -o projectit.o
g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rgdal.dll tmp.def OGR_write.o gdal-bindings.o init.o inverser.o local_stubs.o ogr_geom.o ogr_polygons.o ogr_proj.o ogrdrivers.o ogrsource.o proj6.o proj_info6.o proj_network7.o projectit.o -lgdal -lblosc -lkea -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5 -lgta -lsqlite3 -lmysqlclient -lspatialite -lminizip -lproj -lgeos_c -lgeos -ljson-c -lnetcdf -lpq -lpoppler -llcms2 -lfreetype -lharfbuzz -lfreetype -llz4 -lpcre2-8 -lwebp -lcurl -lidn2 -lunistring -lssh2 -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lssl -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lsz -lexpat -lfreexl -lmfhdf -ldf -lportablexdr -lpcre -lopenjp2 -ljasper -lpng -ljpeg -ltiff -lwebp -lgeotiff -lgif -lxml2 -llzma -lodbc32 -lodbccp32 -liconv -lpsapi -lwldap32 -lsecur32 -lgdi32 -lnormaliz -lbz2 -lzstd -lz -lcrypto -lcrypt32 -lcfitsio -lws2_32 -LC:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(LERC_band.cpp.obj):LERC_band.cpp:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `lerc_getBlobInfo'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(LERC_band.cpp.obj):LERC_band.cpp:(.text+0x714): undefined reference to `lerc_decode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(LERC_band.cpp.obj):LERC_band.cpp:(.text+0x3313): undefined reference to `lerc_encodeForVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_band_refineINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERS5_S7_yyRKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EEb[_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_band_refineINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERS5_S7_yyRKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EEb]+0xbfa): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgbsvx_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_sympd_refineINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EEb[_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_sympd_refineINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EEb]+0x670): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dposvx_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib19solve_square_refineINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EEb[_ZN4arma6auxlib19solve_square_refineINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EEb]+0x6cc): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgesvx_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x183): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dlange_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x1b0): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgetrf_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x201): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgetrs_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib18solve_square_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEERNS4_8pod_typeES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x620): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgecon_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x22a): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dlansy_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x253): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dpotrf_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x57e): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dpotrs_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_sympd_rcondINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEERbRS5_S7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x642): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dpocon_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_square_fastINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib17solve_square_fastINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x148): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgesv_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib16solve_approx_svdINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib16solve_approx_svdINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x53d): undefined reference to `wrapper2_ilaenv_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib16solve_approx_svdINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib16solve_approx_svdINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x6a7): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgelsd_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib16solve_approx_svdINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib16solve_approx_svdINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_8pod_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x79a): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgelsd_'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(gdallinearsystem.cpp.obj):gdallinearsystem.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib15solve_rect_fastINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib15solve_rect_fastINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS2_INT_9elem_typeEEES7_RKNS_4BaseIS5_S4_EE]+0x5a4): undefined reference to `wrapper2_dgels_'
[...]
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-psl.o):psl.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `psl_builtin'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-rand.o):rand.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `BCryptGenRandom'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-rand.o):rand.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `BCryptGenRandom'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `psl_check_version_number'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x357): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x362): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDestroyInstance'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDecompressStream'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDestroyInstance'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderGetErrorCode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x410): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderCreateInstance'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-cookie.o):cookie.c:(.text+0x1166): undefined reference to `psl_is_cookie_domain_acceptable'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCCleanup':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:966:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:968:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCPostEncode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:801:(.text+0x56f): undefined reference to `lerc_encodeForVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:837:(.text+0x7ad): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress_bound'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:845:(.text+0x7da): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:824:(.text+0x83e): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCPreDecode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:331:(.text+0xeff): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_decompress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:403:(.text+0xf3d): undefined reference to `lerc_getBlobInfo'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:476:(.text+0x1037): undefined reference to `lerc_decode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:323:(.text+0x1269): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:476:(.text+0x1382): undefined reference to `lerc_decode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCVSetField':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:1103:(.text+0x16a4): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPCleanup':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:551:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:553:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPEncode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:423:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress_bound'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:430:(.text+0x312): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:405:(.text+0x3a3): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPDecode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:215:(.text+0x832): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_decompress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:206:(.text+0x948): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPVSetField':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:597:(.text+0xb9b): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgdal'
* removing 'C:/Users/Hel/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/rgdal'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal_1.6-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> 


I was having the exact same problem and diagnostics. I found the solution in this thread with comment from DaveArmstrong; the issue seems to be with installing *.tar.gz files from https://cran.r-project.org/, however, it works using *.zip binaries from https://download.r-forge.r-project.org. The following worked for me installing the last version of rgdal:
url <- "https://download.r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/rgdal_1.6-7.zip"
install.packages(url, type="source", repos=NULL)

For future humans, I have archived the rgdal_1.6-7 Windows binary on TheWayBackMachine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20240804101611/https://download.r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/rgdal_1.6-7.zip
